# nodejs get video dureation

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I've been trying this for ages now and I'm not making any progress.
I found this on google https://gist.github.com/Elements-/cf063254730cd754599e
and it's running but when I put that in a function and try to use it with my code its not running.

Code:

```
fs.readdir(`${__dirname}/data`, (err, files) => {
        if (err) return console.error(`[ERROR] ${err}`);

        files.forEach(file => {
            if (file.endsWith(".mp4")) {
                
                // getVideoDuration(`${__dirname}/data/${file}`)
                group = new Group(file.split(".")[0], file, null, getVideoDuration(`${__dirname}/data/${file}`), 0);
                groups.push(group);
            }
        });

        console.log(groups);
    });

function getVideoDuration(video) {
    var buff = new Buffer.alloc(100);
    fs.open(video, 'r', function (err, fd) {
        fs.read(fd, buff, 0, 100, 0, function (err, bytesRead, buffer) {
            var start = buffer.indexOf(new Buffer.from('mvhd')) + 17;
            var timeScale = buffer.readUInt32BE(start, 4);
            var duration = buffer.readUInt32BE(start + 4, 4);
            var movieLength = Math.floor(duration / timeScale);

            console.log('time scale: ' + timeScale);
            console.log('duration: ' + duration);
            console.log('movie length: ' + movieLength + ' seconds');
            return movieLength;
        });
    });
}
```

Output:

```
[
  Group {
    _name: 'vid',
    _video: 'vid.mp4',
    _master: null,
    _maxTime: undefined,
    _currentTime: 0
  },
  Group {
    _name: 'vid2',
    _video: 'vid2.mp4',
    _master: null,
    _maxTime: undefined,
    _currentTime: 0
  }
]
time scale: 153600
duration: 4636416
movie length: 30 seconds
time scale: 153600
duration: 4636416
movie length: 30 seconds
```

its logging the information correctly but is returning undefined

Comment: My guess is that returning inside the callback isn't returning in getVideoDuration. You could try putting a return in front of fs.open and fs.read, or just use the sync versions of those functions so you don't have to deal with callbacks, and just return at the end.

Comment: I tried return at the end but its still undefined

Comment: Can you post your full code? What is the Group object?

Comment: https://hastebin.com/ewoxegacux.js

Comment: Does this do it? https://hastebin.com/ufiqotibod.js If this solves the issue I can write it up into a proper answer.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/umemenujes.cs Thats what Im still getting

Comment: Did you change the code I put in the hastebin? I switched from using callbacks to promises, so the error about callbacks seems strange.

Comment: THanks for that! I forgot to put the .promises on the fs constant!

Comment: Glad it's working! I'll post a proper answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the [last comment](https://gist.github.com/Elements-/cf063254730cd754599e#gistcomment-3241210) of the gist you sent, I came up with this:

```
const fs = require("fs").promises;

class Group {
  constructor(name, video, master, maxTime, currentTime) {
    this._name = name;
    this._video = video;
    this._master = master;
    this._maxTime = maxTime;
    this._currentTime = currentTime;
  }

  setMaster(master) {
    if (this._master != null) {
      this._master.emit('master');
    }

    this._master = master;
    this._master.emit('master');
  }
};

const asyncForEach = async (array, callback) => {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
};

async function loadGroups() {
  const files = await fs.readdir(`${__dirname}/data`);

  const groups = []

  await asyncForEach(files, async file => {

    if (file.endsWith(".mp4")) {
      const duration = await getVideoDuration(`${__dirname}/data/${file}`);
      const group = new Group(file.split(".")[0], file, null, duration, 0);
      groups.push(group);
    }
  });

  console.log(groups);
}

async function getVideoDuration(video) {
  const buff = Buffer.alloc(100);
  const header = Buffer.from("mvhd");
  const file = await fs.open(video, "r");
  const {
    buffer
  } = await file.read(buff, 0, 100, 0);

  await file.close();

  const start = buffer.indexOf(header) + 17;
  const timeScale = buffer.readUInt32BE(start);
  const duration = buffer.readUInt32BE(start + 4);

  const audioLength = Math.floor((duration / timeScale) * 1000) / 1000;

  return audioLength;
}

loadGroups();
```

As to why your original code wasn't working, my guess is that returning inside the callback to `fs.open` or `fs.read` doesn't return for `getVideoDuration`. I couldn't easily figure out a way from the `fs` docs to figure out how to return the value of the callback, so I just switched over to promises and async/await, which will essentially run the code synchronously. This way you can save the output of `fs.open` and `fs.read` and use them to return a value in the scope of `getVideoDuration`.

Comment: What time unit does this return? I need it to be seconds

Comment: Ok its already in seconds. But I have a video thats about 40 minutes long and its giving 50.223 seconds?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure on the math behind this, I simply adapted the code from the gist. I tried looking into the get-video-duration package, but that uses ffprobe behind the scenes instead of reading data from a buffer.

Comment: Its alright I've figured out a "better" way of getting the duration and Im going to post it soon as an answer

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a lot of extra work for little benefit, so I'm going to refer to `get-video-duration` https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-video-duration which does a great job of getting durations of any video file in seconds minutes and hours

Comment: I've seen that but I need to run this on a raspberry pi and apparently that library is  giving me an error:  throw new Error('Unsupported platform/architecture: ' + platform);
 ^

Error: Unsupported platform/architecture: linux-arm64

Comment: Aah bummer, most of the node modules depend on amd architecture

Comment: Its running on my ubuntu pc

Comment: most PC and laptops have amd architecture whereas most portable devices such as mobile phones and controllers are running arm processors, 

that's why it runs on your ubuntu pc

Comment: This lib use ffprobe executable, maybe you must install it https://gist.github.com/enzanki-ars/7d67996a90883e928bc1dd2db7ef0351

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a work-around for this problem.

```
async function test() {
    const duration = await getDuration(`${__dirname}/data/vid.mp4`);
    console.log(duration);
}
test();

function getDuration(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec(`ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 ${file}`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            resolve(stdout ? stdout : stderr);
        });
    });
}
```

I only tested it on linux so I dont know if it'll work on windows